# Semantic representation of text

Tags: nlp, semantics

I am trying to expand my knowledge in natural language processing and I recently came across concept of semantic representation of text.

I understand its definition "an abstract language in which meanings can be represented", but what are some ways to create semantics representation of text? I can't find a satisfying answer for that.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest semantic representation of text would be transforming text into propositions:

*If you get stressed or you don't eat well, then you get ill.*

could be represented as:

> *get_stressed ∨  ¬eat_well → get_ill*

in logic.

A sub-field called Semantic Role Labeling of NLP (with many rich resources propBank, verbNet, frameNet ...) is something you may find useful to look at, also. Especially, representing verbs with their roles, agents, direct-indirect objects or prepositions, sentences are represented as graphs serving semantics. Jurafsky has a chapter for SLR in chapter 18 in his book here : [Chapter 18 - Semantic Role Labeling and Argument Structure](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/18.pdf)

As in Jurafsky's sample, a verb's arguments could be extracted in a sentence:

> John[AGENT] *broke* the window[THEME] with a rock[INSTRUMENT].

and could be simply represented like:  ***break***(John, the window, a rock)

[Complete Book link](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/)

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it was really helpful.

Comment: You are welcome, glad that you found it useful guys.